# Do we need to define spring.profile.active in yml if declaring user defined environment variable in PCF?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, cloud-foundry

On Pivotal Cloud Foundry, say I define this user defined environment variable as SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE with value say DEV, then do I need to define in bootstrap.yml, SPRING.PROFILE.ACTIVE (but in the yml way) and define the profile name?

Also is this a reserved environment variable? I was not able to find it in PCF docs.

I was thinking of an approach of defining a random user defined variable name on PCF (say ACTIVE_PROFILE) and then in my bootstrap.yml refer to it as spring.profiles.active = ${ACTIVE_PROFILE: local} where I have flexibility to mention the default. Want to understand what is the difference between two approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the property is spring.profile**s**.active (plural) and its used to set all active profiles.

Setting the environment variable SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE is doing the same as setting the property spring.profiles.active in a properties file. So when you set the environment variable, you do not need to set it in the property/yaml file.

Spring profiles and properties provide a very flexible way to configure your application. The order in which configurations are supplied and how defaults are calculated is complex enough. So I would not use a different name 'ACTIVE_PROFILE' for the same property or another way of defaulting unless really needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: For local development, in my windows environment variable I added the same variable with value local but the local profile does not work

Comment: Figured it out.